# Why is my add method in my directory program setting the first four fields to null in my text file when I add a new person?

Tags: java, arrays, directory

I have a text file containing all the persons in my program (staff, employee, instructor, and students) and their relevant information depending on the type of person. I have a directory class with all my methods, and a directoryServer which is the interface class.

My add method is not working properly because when I add a new type of person, it sets the first four fields to null when I try to update my text file. Also after I add a new person and then try to find (find is another method in my program), it says the name is not in the directory even though it is. The fields after the fourth field are what the user inputted, which is showing in my text file correctly.

This is my add method and close method in my directory class:

```
   public boolean add(Person obj) throws IOException { 
      boolean added = true;
      String s = obj.toString();
      dir[directorySize++] = s;
      return added;
   }        

   public void closeDirectory() {
      directoryDataIn.close();
      PrintStream directoryDataOut = null;
      try {
          directoryDataOut = new PrintStream(directoryFile);
      }
      catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
         System.out.printf("File %s not found, exiting!", directoryFile);
         System.exit(0);
      }
      String originalDirectory[] = {"Staff 77778 Julie Chang Registrar","Adjunct 19778 Mike Thompson CS mtxxx@gmail.com GITC2400", "Staff 30041 Anne Mathews Security","Junior 98444 Serene Murray Math smyyy@gmail.com", "Freshman 98772 Bob Mathew CS bmyyy@gmail.com","Professor 19010 Joan Berry Math jbxxx@gmail.com GITC2315C","Professor 19871 Aparna Khat CS akxxx@gmail.com GITC1400","Adjunct 18821 Hari Mentor Physics hmxxx@gmail.com CK231","Staff 20112 Jim George Plant","Junior 68339 Tom Harry CS thyyy@gmail.com","Senior 78883 Vince Charles IT vcyyy@gmail.com","Freshman 87777 Susan Han EE shyyy@gmail.com","Senior 88888 Janki Khat IE jkyyy@gmail.com","Staff 5555 Aparna Sen Plant","Senior 66663 Jill Kaley it jk@jk.com","Staff 77777 Joe Batra plumbing","Staff 33333 Jim Natale Plumbing"};

      if (originalDirectory == dir) //do not update text file if no changes were made
         System.exit(0);
      else
         for (int i = 0; i < directorySize; i++)
            directoryDataOut.println(dir[i]);
         directoryDataOut.close();
   }
```

And this is what an excerpt of my text file is supposed to look like:

```
Senior 88888 Janki Khat IE jkyyy@gmail.com
```

But it comes out like this instead:

```
null null null null MATH rwood@njit.edu
```

How can I fix this? 
For some reason, this faulty output just came today. I closed and saved all my class files last week when everything was working correctly.

This is my Person class

```
public class Person {
   private String Position;
   private String UCID;
   private String FirstName;
   private String LastName;

   public Person(String Position, String UCID, String FirstName, String LastName) {
      Position = Position;
      UCID = UCID;
      FirstName = FirstName;
      LastName = LastName;
   }

   public String toString() {
   return String.format("%s %s %s %s", Position, UCID, FirstName, LastName);

   }
}
```

And this is from my directoryServer class. In this excerpt of code I'm adding a professor or adjunct. Before this part I'm just using a scanner object to get user input for each field line by line.

```
       p = new Instructor(pos, ucid, fname, lname, dept, email, office);
       try { 
          d.add(p);
       }
       catch (Exception e) {
       System.out.println("Error, cannot add");
       continue;
       }
```

Comment: What is happening in the `toString()` of `Person`?

Comment: @npinti I see you added it in the question, thanks

Comment: can you also show how you creating Person obj while calling add method ?

Comment: Are you initializing the fields of the Person objects? Can we see where you create the Person objects?

Comment: And are all the variables of type string or are they some other composite object?

Comment: @jimmy just updated the question with that additional code

Comment: @npinti all variables are strings except UCID is an integer

Comment: now can you also post your constructor? and also how you are parsing those values before passing it to constructor. if possible , debug your code and see if `p` is populated with all fields.

Comment: use `this` keyword in your constructor. both of them referencing to the local variable, not the instance variable. what that means is , your object will never be assigned with any values when you use this constructor. as a result, it will always be null.

Comment: @Jimmy Right!! I had this in my original program but then took it out thinking it would still work without it. That explains why it was working previously and stopped all of a sudden. But yes my problem is solved now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the in Person class. You need to use statements like:

```
this.Position = Position
```

else you are just assigning local variables to local variables.

Additionally, for stylistic reasons, you want instance variables (fields) to be lower case.

Answer (score 0):

In your add method line:

```
      String s = obj.toString();
```

Probably returns wrong `String` representation of `Person` class. Have you properly overwritten `public string toString()` method?

In the same method I would also advice to take care of line:

```
 dir[directorySize++] = s;
```

arrays have fixed size, which is specified during the initialization. In some point in the future you will face `IndexOutOfBounds` exception, as there will be no space for inserting new record. I would suggest using `LinkedList` instead, which can be dynamically enlarged with new records.

All in all it is pretty hard to give specified solution for your problem without seeing `Person` class, and your code, which is responsible for populating your text file

Comment: I just added the entire Person class code. Can you take a look and see what might be the issue? @tinki